# Complex model binding in ado.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am getting a table from database. The table is getting using joins of other table. I am struggling to bind it with my model. Insert data into both table is working.

I am getting the values from database but don't know how to convert address into list.

```
public class address
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string peopleaddress { get; set; }
}

public class People
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string address { get; set; }
    public List<string> cityid  { get; set; }    // is equal to people address
    public string shortimagepath { get; set; }
    public string fullimagepath { get; set; }
}
```

This one is my `dbcontext` class using ado.net

```
    public List<People> selectallpeople()
    {
        List<People> peopleslist = new List<People>();
        List<address> addresses = new List<address>();

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection=new SqlConnection(dbconnect))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("selectallpeople", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(datatable);

            foreach (DataRow item in datatable.Rows)
            {
                addresses.Add(new address
                {
                    peopleaddress = item["address"].ToString(),
                });

                peopleslist.Add(new People
                {
                    id = (int)item["id"],
                    Name = item["name"].ToString(),
                    LastName = item["lastname"].ToString(),
                    shortimagepath = item["imageshortpath"].ToString(),
                    // I am struggling here to bind address column to list of address
                });
            }

            return peopleslist;
        }
```

I am getting all values from database but I need to bind multiple address to list of addresses.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your question more...

Comment: @NoChance how to bind a coloumn with   public List<string> cityid .a person has many addresses so how to bind those many addresses to a person simple

Comment: I am not clear what you want! but may be helpfull `string addressListSepartedbyCommas = string.Join(",", address Array)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my solution. Hope to help and Happy new year, my friend :))

```
foreach (DataRow item in datatable.Rows)
{
                int idObj = (int)item["id"] //This Id for both, right?           
                addresses.Add(new address
                {
                    id = idObj,
                    peopleaddress = item["address"].ToString(),
                });

                peopleslist.Add(new People
                {
                    id = (int)item["id"],
                    Name = item["name"].ToString(),
                    LastName = item["lastname"].ToString(),
                    shortimagepath = item["imageshortpath"].ToString(),
                    // I am struggling here to bind address column to list of address
                    cityid  = addresses.Where(t => t.id == idObj)
                             .Select(t=>t.peopleaddress.ToString()).ToList()
                });


}
```

In the View you can show cityid like this:

```
foreach(var item in peopleslist)
{
     var lstCityId = String.Join(",", item.cityid).ToString();    
}
```

Comment: its seems like binding all address to every customer i need to bind one customer to their many address not everyaddress.@tomato32

Comment: Please, improve readability of your answer. When you write the answer, there's a preview beneath it. Consider taking a look at it.

Comment: @ahmedshah: You need to filter the data first. I edited my solution. Please refer it. Sorry for responding late my friend.

Comment: @JohnyL: I'm really sorry about that. I edited it. Happy new year, my friend :))